# Xpages repeat value depends on a value outside of the repeat

Tags: xpages, repeat, xpages-ssjs

Hardly I managed to build a repeat with 2 inputText that do some math depending on the value of another inputText(let's call it outside_input) which is outside the repeat.

Everything is working fine, but the problem is when I want to change the value of the outside_input the values of the inputTexts inside the repeat doens't automatically refresh. I have a partial refresh on the repeat.

The 2 fields inside the Repeat are binded with a viewScope. And the script is on the first field on the onChange method.

Is there a way that when I change the outside_input I could trigger the onChange method of the inner fields?

Comment: Seeing your code would be helpful in visualizing this, though I think Howard's probably nailed this one.

Answer (score 0):

Put the partial refresh on the first field (that has the onChange event) and specify to refresh the repeat or a panel that contains the repeat and whatever other fields rely on it. Note that this requires your onChange event to be server side code not client side code.

Howard

Comment: Yes, I have this, the problem is that the partial refresh on the outside field is not working. Because, I think, I have the code inside the onChange method, and that field inside the repeat is not changed.